# Splitting a variable into equally sized groups

Tags: r, split

I have a continuous variable called `Longitude` (it corresponds to geographical longitude) that has 12465 unique values. I need to create a new variable called `Longitude1024` that consists of the variable Longitude split into 1024 equally sized groups. I did that using the following function:

```
data$Longitude1024 <- as.factor( as.numeric( cut(data$Longitude,1024)))
```

However, the problem is that, when I use this function to create the new variable `Longitude1024`, this new variable consists of only 651 unique elements rather than 1024. Does anyone know what the problem here is and how could I actually get the new variable with 1024 unique values?

Thanks a lot

Comment: your data is probably not evenly distributed, so when you cut like that some of the bins will have 0 values.  You can do `cut(dat, quantile(dat, probs=seq(0,1,1/1024))`

Comment: or `gtools::quantcut`

Comment: maybe a better way, `split(dat[order(dat)], c(0, seq(length(dat)))%/%2)`, and replace 2 with the number of values you want per bin

Answer (score 1):

Use `rank`, then scale it down. Here's an example with 10 groups:

```
x <- rnorm(124655)
g <- floor(rank(x) * 10 / (length(x) + 1))
table(g)
# g
#     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9 
# 12465 12466 12465 12466 12465 12466 12466 12465 12466 12465
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:  try `cut2` from the `Hmisc` package**

**Long answer**

Example:  split `dat`, which is 1000 unique values, into 100 equal groups of 10.

**Doesn't work:**

```
# dummy data
set.seed(321)
dat <- rexp(1000)

# all unique values
length(unique(dat))
[1] 1000
```

`cut` generates 100 levels

```
init_res <- cut(dat, 100)
length(unique(levels(init_res)))
[1] 100
```

But does not split the data into equally sized groups

```
init_grps <- split(dat, cut(dat, 100))
table(unlist(lapply(init_grps, length)))
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9 10 11 13 15 17 18 19 22 23 24 25 27 37 38 44 47 50 63 71 72 77 
 42  9  8  4  1  3  1  3  2  1  2  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  2  2  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1
```

**Works with Hmisc::cut2**

`cut2` divides the vector into groups of equal length, as desired

```
require(Hmisc)
final_grps <- split(dat, cut2(dat, g=100))
table(unlist(lapply(final_grps, length)))
 10 
 100
```

If you want, you can store the results in a data frame, for example

```
foobar <- do.call(rbind, final_grps)
head(foobar)
                          [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]         [,8]
[0.000611,0.00514) 0.004345915 0.002192086 0.004849693 0.002911516 0.003421753 0.003159641 0.004855366 0.0006111574
[0.005137,0.01392) 0.009178133 0.005137309 0.008347482 0.007072484 0.008732725 0.009379002 0.008818794 0.0110489833
[0.013924,0.02004) 0.014283326 0.014356782 0.013923721 0.014290554 0.014895342 0.017992638 0.015608931 0.0173707930
[0.020041,0.03945) 0.023047527 0.020437743 0.026353839 0.036159321 0.024371834 0.026629812 0.020793695 0.0214221779
[0.039450,0.05912) 0.043379064 0.039450453 0.050806316 0.054778805 0.040093806 0.047228050 0.055058519 0.0446634954
[0.059124,0.07362) 0.069671018 0.059124220 0.063242564 0.064505875 0.072344089 0.067196661 0.065575249 0.0634142853
                      [,9]       [,10]
[0.000611,0.00514) 0.002524557 0.003155055
[0.005137,0.01392) 0.008287758 0.011683228
[0.013924,0.02004) 0.018537469 0.014847937
[0.020041,0.03945) 0.026233400 0.020040981
[0.039450,0.05912) 0.041310471 0.058449603
[0.059124,0.07362) 0.063608022 0.066316782
```

Hope this helps